# How to remove labels but preserve hanging indenting in the memoir class

Tags: bibliographies, indentation, memoir, thesis

I am writing my humanities PhD in the `memoir` class. I need to have hanging indents for the bibliography, but no numbers or bullets. I have added

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother
```

to the preamble, which removes the numbering, but I can't get the hanging indents to come back. Any suggestions?

Comment: The way to do this is by using an appropriate bibliography style for your field.  Are you using `bibtex` to manage your reference?  I hope you're not entering them by hand.

Comment: Also, switch to `biblatex` sooner rather than later: it is the only way to get the flexibility you're likely to need (esp. if you work in the humanities).

Answer (score 1):

hanging indentation is a property if the list list being used to typeset the list. Removing the label will not change that. If you want to change it manually copy and change the memoir code for the `bibitemlist` environment.

Here is one way of doing it. But I agree with the others use `BibTeX` instead, most of the author year systems are typeset in the manner you ask for. You may also get even more flexibility using `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} % sample text
\makeatletter
\setlength\bibindent{2.5em}
\renewcommand\@openbib@code{%
   \leftmargin\bibindent
  \itemindent -\bibindent
  \listparindent \parindent
  \parsep \z@
  \labelsep0pt
}%
\setbiblabel{} % this does what you were doing, memoir has interface
\makeatother
\aliaspagestyle{plain}{showlocs} % to show that the text is at the edge
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{t} \lipsum[1-2]
\bibitem{s} \lipsum[2]
\bibitem{r} \lipsum[1-2]
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```